# Wait for useContext Object in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to set up a PrivateRouter in React and I'm finding that the following code redirect to login page due to context variable is null although the currentUser object exists.

Is there any way to wait for those context variables or another approach to solve this routing issue?

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { AuthContext} from "./Auth";

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: RouteComponent, ...rest }) => {

  const {currentUser} = useContext(AuthContext);

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={routeProps =>
        !!currentUser ? (
          <RouteComponent {...routeProps} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect to={"/login"} />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};
export default PrivateRoute
```

Comment: you need to maintain a loading state. You can have that in the AuthContext provider itself

Answer (score 0):

I answer it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63478324/9404135
Also, you can check out the other answer in that question.

I have this problem today, I like what Shubham does. But the way I solve it is just getting the `userinfo` from the previous component and pass it to this `profile` component.

However, make sure you render the `Profile` component like this so that you can make sure the `userinfo` exists:

```
function ParentComponent(){
 // do sth to get the userinfo here
return(
  <ParentComponent>
     {userinfo? <Profile userinfo={userinfo} /> : null}       
 <ParentComponent/>
)
}
```